# Best way to count all rows in a 2d numpy array that include all elements of another 1d array?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

What is the best way to count the rows in a 2d numpy array that include all values of another 1d numpy array? The 2nd array can have more columns than the length of the 1d array.

```py
elements = np.arange(4).reshape((2, 2))
test_elements = [2, 3]
somefunction(elements, test_elements)
```

I would expect the function to return 1.

```py
elements = np.arange(15).reshape((5, 3))

# array([[ 0,  1,  2],
#       [ 3,  4,  5],
#       [ 6,  7,  8],
#       [ 9, 10, 11],
#       [12, 13, 14]])

test_elements = [4, 3]
somefunction(elements, test_elements)
```

Should also return 1.

All elements of the 1d array must be included. If only a few elements are found in a row, it doesn't count. Hence:

```py
elements = np.arange(15).reshape((5, 3))

# array([[ 0,  1,  2],
#       [ 3,  4,  5],
#       [ 6,  7,  8],
#       [ 9, 10, 11],
#       [12, 13, 14]])

test_elements = [3, 4, 10]
somefunction(elements, test_elements)
```

Should also return 0.

Comment: `(elements == test_elements).all(1).sum()`

Comment: You can not do better than `O(m)` where m is number of elements in `elements` array.

Comment: @norok2 Good idea. I've added another one that should show more clearly what I mean.

Comment: What would happen for `elements = np.arange(15).reshape((5, 3))` and `test_elements = [1, 3, 4]`?

Comment: @norok2 I think it should be `2`.

Comment: @Vishnudev based on the title should be 0.

Comment: @Poojan Should it be O(mxn) where m is the number of elements in the input array and n is the number of elements in the search array.

Comment: @DavidJM Is the `test_elements` array always of the same length as the number of columns in `elements`?

Comment: @norok2 Yes, it should be 0. None of the rows contain all 3 of the values in test_elements.

Comment: @ishan The length of the 1d array can be different than the number of columns of the 2d array. Usually the 1d array is longer.

Comment: @DavidJM So, what numbers are we talking about? I'd expect the 1d array to be smaller than number of columns of 2d array, but are we talking about `len(test_elements)` as `100` or `100000`?

Comment: `len(test_elements)` would probably be around 400-500. `elements` would have around 80k to 100k rows.

Answer (score 0):

Create a boolean array of elements found then use any row-wise this will avoid multiple values in the same row and at last count the rows by using sum,

```
np.any(np.isin(elements, test), axis=1).sum()
```

**Output**

```
>>> elements
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14]])
>>> test = [1, 6, 7, 4]
>>> np.any(np.isin(elements, test), axis=1).sum()
3
```

Comment: Thanks. But that counts all rows that include any values of the 1d array. I'm looking for something that requires that ALL values of the 1d array must be in the row of the 2d array.

Comment: @DavidJM Could you justify your second example?

Comment: In second example, the test_elements are [4, 3]. Both 3 and 4 are included in the second row in elements. Order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

(**EDIT**: OK, now I actually had a bit more time to figure out what is going on.)

---

The are two issues here:

1. the computational complexity depends on the sizes of both inputs and it is not captured well by a 1D benchmark plot
2. the actual timing are dominated by variation in the inputs

The problem can be separated in two parts:

1. looping through the rows
2. performing the subset check, which is basically a nested-loop quadratic operation (in the worst-case scenario)

We know that, *for sufficiently large inputs*, looping through the rows is *faster* in NumPy and *slower* in pure Python.

For reference, let's consider these two approaches:

```
# pure Python approach
def all_in_by_row_flt(arr, elems=ELEMS):
    return sum(1 for row in arr if all(e in row for e in elems))

# NumPy apprach (based on @Mstaino answer)
def all_in_by_row_np(arr, elems=ELEMS):
    def _aaa_helper(row, e=elems):
        return np.isin(e, row)
    return np.sum(np.all(np.apply_along_axis(_aaa_helper, 1, arr), 1))
```

Then, considering the subset check operation, if the input is such that the check is performed within fewer loops, pure Python looping gets faster than NumPy. Conversely, if a sufficiently large number of loops is required, then NumPy can actually be faster.
On top of this, there is the looping through the rows, but because the subset check operation is quadratic AND the have different constant coefficients, there are situations for which, despite the rows-looping being faster in NumPy (because the number of rows would be sufficiently large), the overall operation *is* faster in pure Python.
This was the situation I was running into in the earlier benchmarks, and corresponds to the situation where the subset check is always (or almost) `False` and it does fail within few loops.
As soon as the subset check starts requiring more loops, the Python only approach begins to lag behind and for the situation where the subset check is actually `True` for most (if not all) the rows, the NumPy approach *is* actually faster.

Another key difference between the NumPy and the pure Python approach is that pure Python uses lazy evaluation and NumPy does not, and actually require the creation of potentially large intermediate objects that slow down the computation.
On top of this, NumPy iterates over the rows twice (one in `sum()` and one in `np.apply_along_axis()`), while the pure Python approaches only once.

---

Other approaches using `set().issubset()` like e.g. from @GZ0 answer:

```
def all_in_by_row_set(arr, elems=ELEMS):
    elems = set(elems)
    return sum(map(elems.issubset, row))
```

have different timings than the explicitly writing of the nested-loop when it comes to subset checking, but they still suffer from slower outer looping.

---

## So, what's next?

The answer is to use [Cython](https://cython.org/) or [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/).
The idea is to get NumPy-like (read: C) speed all the times (and not only for sufficiently large inputs), lazy evaluation and minimal number of looping through the rows.

An example of a Cython approach (as implemented in IPython, using the `%load_ext Cython` magic) is:

```
%%cython --cplus -c-O3 -c-march=native -a
#cython: language_level=3, boundscheck=False, wraparound=False, initializedcheck=False, cdivision=True


cdef long all_in_by_row_c(long[:, :] arr, long[:] elems) nogil:
    cdef long result = 0
    I = arr.shape[0]
    J = arr.shape[1]
    K = elems.shape[0]
    for i in range(I):
        is_subset = True
        for k in range(K):
            is_contained = False
            for j in range(J):
                if elems[k] == arr[i, j]:
                    is_contained = True
                    break
            if not is_contained:
                is_subset = False
                break
        result += 1 if is_subset else 0
    return result


def all_in_by_row_cy(long[:, :] arr, long[:] elems):
    return all_in_by_row_c(arr, elems)
```

While a similar Numba code reads:

```
import numba as nb


@nb.jit(nopython=True, nogil=True)
def all_in_by_row_jit(arr, elems=ELEMS):
    result = 0
    n_rows, n_cols = arr.shape
    for i in range(n_rows):
        is_subset = True
        for e in elems:
            is_contained = False
            for r in arr[i, :]:
                if e == r:
                    is_contained = True
                    break
            if not is_contained:
                is_subset = False
                break
        result += 1 if is_subset else 0
    return result
```

Now, time-wise we get to the following (for relatively small number of rows):

```
arr.shape=(100, 1000) elems.shape=(1000,) result=0
Func: all_in_by_row_cy  120 µs ± 1.07 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
Func: all_in_by_row_jit 129 µs ± 131 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
Func: all_in_by_row_flt 2.44 ms ± 13.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
Func: all_in_by_row_set 9.98 ms ± 52.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
Func: all_in_by_row_np  13.7 ms ± 52.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

arr.shape=(100, 2000) elems.shape=(1000,) result=0
Func: all_in_by_row_cy  1.45 ms ± 24.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
Func: all_in_by_row_jit 1.52 ms ± 4.16 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
Func: all_in_by_row_flt 30.1 ms ± 452 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
Func: all_in_by_row_set 19.8 ms ± 56.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
Func: all_in_by_row_np  18 ms ± 28.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

arr.shape=(100, 3000) elems.shape=(1000,) result=37
Func: all_in_by_row_cy  10.4 ms ± 31.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
Func: all_in_by_row_jit 10.9 ms ± 13.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
Func: all_in_by_row_flt 226 ms ± 2.67 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Func: all_in_by_row_set 30.5 ms ± 92.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
Func: all_in_by_row_np  21.9 ms ± 87.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

arr.shape=(100, 4000) elems.shape=(1000,) result=86
Func: all_in_by_row_cy  16.8 ms ± 32.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
Func: all_in_by_row_jit 17.7 ms ± 42 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
Func: all_in_by_row_flt 385 ms ± 2.33 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Func: all_in_by_row_set 39.5 ms ± 588 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
Func: all_in_by_row_np  25.7 ms ± 128 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Now that the slow down of the last block cannot be explained by the increased input size in the second dimension.
Actually, if the *short-circuit rate* is increased (e.g. by changing the values range of the random arrays), for the last block (same input sizes) one gets:

```
arr.shape=(100, 4000) elems.shape=(1000,) result=0
Func: all_in_by_row_cy   152 µs ± 1.89 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
Func: all_in_by_row_jit  173 µs ± 4.72 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
Func: all_in_by_row_flt  556 µs ± 8.56 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
Func: all_in_by_row_set  39.7 ms ± 287 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
Func: all_in_by_row_np   31.5 ms ± 315 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Note that `set()`-based method is kind of independent on the *short-circuit rate* (because of the hash-based implementation which has `~O(1)` check for presence complexity, but this comes at the expenses of hashing pre-computation and these results indicate this might not be faster than the direct nested-looping approach).

Finally, for larger rows counts :

```
arr.shape=(100000, 1000) elems.shape=(1000,) result=0
Func: all_in_by_row_cy  141 ms ± 2.08 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
Func: all_in_by_row_jit 150 ms ± 1.73 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
Func: all_in_by_row_flt 2.6 s ± 28.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Func: all_in_by_row_set 10.1 s ± 216 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Func: all_in_by_row_np  13.7 s ± 15.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

arr.shape=(100000, 2000) elems.shape=(1000,) result=34
Func: all_in_by_row_cy  1.2 s ± 753 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Func: all_in_by_row_jit 1.27 s ± 7.32 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Func: all_in_by_row_flt 24.1 s ± 119 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Func: all_in_by_row_set 19.5 s ± 270 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Func: all_in_by_row_np  18 s ± 18.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

arr.shape=(100000, 3000) elems.shape=(1000,) result=33859
Func: all_in_by_row_cy  9.79 s ± 11.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Func: all_in_by_row_jit 10.3 s ± 5.55 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Func: all_in_by_row_flt 3min 30s ± 1.13 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Func: all_in_by_row_set 30 s ± 57.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Func: all_in_by_row_np  21.9 s ± 59.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

arr.shape=(100000, 4000) elems.shape=(1000,) result=86376
Func: all_in_by_row_cy  17 s ± 30.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Func: all_in_by_row_jit 17.9 s ± 13 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Func: all_in_by_row_flt 6min 29s ± 293 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Func: all_in_by_row_set 38.9 s ± 33 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Func: all_in_by_row_np  25.7 s ± 29.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Finally, note that the Cython/Numba code *may* be algorithmically optimized.

Comment: That's the implementation that I currently have. But it's quite slow when the 2d array is bigger. Was hopping for some magically way that is faster ;)

Comment: @DavidJM check out the update benchmarks, but this would depend on how much big is big for you. Perhaps you can give some indication on the sizes of your objects. My workstation will not fit much larger objects into memory though, but ~500 ms for crunching ~80k rows doesn't seem too bad to me :-)

Comment: @DavidJM With numbers close to your use-case, I know see why you were disappointed with `set()`. However, check out the *new* proposed approach (which was on par with `set()` with the previous battery of tests), using a nested comprehension instead.

Comment: @DavidJM OK, I actually messed up the analysis a bit in earlier edits, please look at this *new* one.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more efficient solution, but if you want the rows where "all" elements of `test_elements` are present, you can reverse `np.isin` and apply it along each row, with the following:

```
np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.isin(test_elements, x), 1, elements).all(1).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more efficient (but less readable) variant of @norok2's solution is the following.

```
sum(map(set(test_elements).issubset, elements))
```

Comment: I would argue it is actually less efficient, since `sum()` will be given all the rows to process, even the `0`/ `False` ones. On the other hand, a `filter()` based method would be much better because `0`s do not reach `sum()`, but that's substantially equivalent to the *filtered* comprehension generator syntax (note that there is no intermediate container being created).

Comment: @norok2 That is actually not the case in my tests. `sum(arr)` runs more than twice as fast as `sum(1 for e in arr if e)` given either `arr = [False] * 1000000` or `arr = [True] * 1000000`. The `filter`-based approach you proposed runs faster than `sum(arr)` on the `False` array but slower on the `True` array.

Comment: @norok2 Explicit generator expressions are compiled into (unnamed) functions. This introduces quite some function call overhead.

Comment: that is not a *apple* to *apple* comparison: (1) when you do `sum(arr)` all your looping lives in C; (2) `sum(arr)` does not include the logic associated to the `if`. Anyway for your peace of mind, I am including your proposed approach in my benchmarks.

Comment: that is correct, but `map()` does have the *same* overhead, something that a plain `sum()` call does not have!

Comment: If you want to do comparison that includes all the logic of `sum(1 for e in arr if e)`, compare it with `sum(filter(bool, arr))` and `sum(map(bool, arr))`. You will see that `filter()` comes out as much faster than `map()`.

Comment: @norok2 Your proposed comparison is problematic as well because for the general case, the logic of `sum(1 for e in arr if pred(e))` is equivalent to `sum(map(pred, e))` and `sum(1 for _ in filter(pred, arr))`. You cannot just write `sum(filter(pred, arr))` unless `arr` itself is a boolean array. I tried the comparison and the result varies on different `pred`s. The `map` approach is actually faster than `filter` for complex `pred`s such as `set.__contains__`.

Comment: at this point I am not sure what you are referring to, but `sum(filter(set(test_elements).issubset, elements))` is 100% valid and workable code AND it is (slightly, in the *average* case) faster than the `map()` counterpart. The equivalent comprehensions are, [for the most part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/list-comprehension-vs-map), equivalent to the `map()` and `filter()` respectively.

Comment: @norok2 `sum(filter(set(test_elements).issubset, elements))` is a valid statement but it does not return the expected result if the result is greater than `0`. The `filter` call returns an iterable over actual elements in `elements` rather than boolean values. Then sum will be taken over the returned rows instead of just `1`s.

Comment: point taken, I was absent-minded there @@, you would need an extra step to make `filter()` work. Anyway I have updated my answer with the timings including your approach. It comes out as pretty much the same as `all_in_by_row_set()` which is what I proposed in my original answer.

Comment: @norok2 The `map` approach is around 10% faster in my tests as long as the # of matched rows is not very small (e.g., over 5% of the total rows examined). As already mentioned in the SO link you provided, `map` is often faster when the exact same function is called in the generator expression. Actually the primary reason why `map` is faster is that it avoids the repeated lookup of the called function.